# Dockerfile preguntar al usuario un valor

Tags: mysql, docker

Buenas tardes compañeros, estoy trabajando con Docker en la construccion de algunas imagenes y me he topado con que alguna instalaciones hacen preguntas al usuario como por ejemplo una contraseña.

Existe la posibilidad de hacer pregunta al usuario durante el proceso de creacion de la imagen y luego pasar ese pasametro para otro comando, por ejemplo este codigo me manda error

`FROM ubuntu:16.04
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN ["echo","========== Enter root password for db =========="]
RUN ["/bin/bash","read","pass"] > Error al momento de compilar
RUN debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $pass"
RUN debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $pass"`

El mensaje de error es el siguiente:

`The command '/bin/bash read pass' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Comment: Se que existe una imagen oficial de mysql para docker, pero me han solicitado crean la imagen a base de ubuntu 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay modo interactivo en `docker build` como hay en `docker run`, si querés pasar parámetros de construcción podés usar `--build-args` [(ver acá)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg) y hacer un script que pida esos valores y ejecute `docker build` con esa opción.

PD: Para manejar contraseñas, lo recomendado es utilizar secrets. MySQL explica como hacerlo con `docker-compose` [(ver)](https://mysqlrelease.com/2017/08/docker-secrets-and-mysql-password-management/) y Docker con `swarm` para producción [(ver)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta compañero, lo que comenta de secrets ya lo habia leido que solo es funcional para servicios en modo swarm y no para contenedores que se ejecutan manualmente. Voy a intentar usar alguna programacion para cambiar ese password de manera dinamica. Un saludo.